# Using Webmatrix, drop down menu to post matched data into text box

Tags: drop-down-menu, webmatrix

I have drop down menu which i choose one item from it and then by using onblur event i can post the match detail into input text box. whenever i choose from the drop menu, the matched detail should posted into the input text box. In my example i will choose a specific industry field and the related questions should be appear in question1 and question2 input text box. Example is below:

```
 var db = Database.Open("me");
 var ind = Request["areagroup"];
 var sqlq = "SELECT id,indName,question1,question2 from Industry where id = @0";
 var data = db.Query(sqlq,ind);



 <select name="areagroup"  onblur="???? ">
    <option value="0">General</option>
    <option value="1">Services</option>
    <option value="2">Basic Materials</option>
 </select>


 <label>Question 1</label><input type="text" name="q1"  />
 <br/>
 <label>Question 2</label><input type="text" name="q2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your target.

The code that follows populates the input fields when the dropdown loses its focus:

```
@{
    var question1 = "";
    var question2 = "";

    if (IsPost)
    {
        if(Request["butt"] != "test"){
            var db = Database.Open("me");
            var ind = Request["areagroup"];
            var sqlq = "SELECT id,indName,question1,question2 from Industry where id = @0";
            var data = db.Query(sqlq,ind);
            question1 = data.question1;
            question2 = data.question2;
        } else {
            // If submit button is pressed
        }
    }
}

<form method="post">
    <select name="areagroup"  onblur="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="0">General</option>
        <option value="1">Services</option>
        <option value="2">Basic Materials</option>
    </select>
    <br/ >
    <label>Question 1</label><input type="text" name="q1" value="@question1"  />
    <br/>
    <label>Question 2</label><input type="text" name="q2" value="@question2" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="butt" value="test" />
</form>
```

I have provided a submit button and an if statement inside the IsPost block to test if the form is submitted by the user.

In my opinion, a better solution is to use the `onchange` instead of the `onblur` event adding a dummy option to the dropdown (something like `<option value="-1">--- Please select ---</option>`).